# Excel Pivot Table - Combine rows

Tags: excel, merge, pivot, excel-2010

I've designed a pivot table with the rows denoting date and time stamps and the columns indicating client names. As indicated by the attached screenshot, there are a number of rows denoting the same date. Is there a way to reduce it or merge the rows/cells so that there is only one row per day?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps -
1. Right click on any one of the dates in column 1 (dates & time).
2. Select "Group..." in the dropdown.
3. In the pop-up select "By" >>> "Days"
4. Select the "Number of days" range, in your case it would be 1.
5. Click OK.

Hopefully you'll get your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to introduce a new column in your data that shows only the date part of the timestamp